# Add Iferror Function to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do you inject the iferror function on this code?

```
For d = 2 To lastrowx2

Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 15).Value, _
Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Range("X:Y"), 2, 0)

Next
```

I just want a null value cells (d, 16) if it is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before the row with `Next`:

```
If IsError(Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 16)) Then
    Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 16) = ""
End If
```

Comment: I like this approach. I will study this furthermore. I want to have more options in doing VBA. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Something like below would do that for you, a nested application function:

```
For d = 2 To lastrowx2

Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 16).Value = Application.IfError( _
    Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Cells(d, 15).Value, _
    Worksheets("Educational Service Report").Range("X:Y"), 2, 0), "")

Next d
```